# Ng-Bootstrap Typeahead Incorrect Style With Google Maps Place Autocomplete

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, google-maps-api-3, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I'm developing an Angular 4 application that uses Ng-Bootstrap's [typeahead directive](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples). In the Wikipedia example, they make an api call to Wikipedia and display the results in the typeahead box. I'm attempting to do the same thing but instead with Google Map's place autocomplete service.

Following the Wikipedia example, I've created a similar service that returns an Rxjs Observable that contains the autocompleted places.

```
search(term: string) {
    if (term === '') {
      return Observable.of([]);
    }

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({ input: term }, (results, status) => {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            observer.next(results.map(result => result.description));
            observer.complete();
          } else {
            console.log('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
            observer.next({});
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
    });
}
```

On the controller side, my code looks like this:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(term =>
            this.service.search(term)
                .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
                .catch(() => {
                    this.searchFailed = true;
                    return Observable.of([]);
                }))
```

This works well, but for some reason, the typeahead bar appears in the incorrect location until something triggers a redraw.

[Note the gap between the input field and the typeahead on the top image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klPeG.png)

Pressing any key or clicking anywhere on the screen instantly corrects it, but I can't figure out how to get it correct the first time.

From my research, it seems like it could be an issue with the Google Maps place autocomplete service running outside of NgZone and not triggering a redraw, but I've had no luck with any of the usual strategies to manually force a redraw (ApplicationRef.tick(), NgZone.run(), ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Plunker with similar behavior: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/iy2Zhd5rEhBK2aVbBqsB/

Comment: Normally `NgZone.run()` should do the trick. Could you put together a plunker that reproduces the issue so we can have a look?

Comment: Where would you recommend doing the NgZone.run()?

Comment: In a place where a call to the external API (google maps) is made. Once again, having a plunker with a reproduce scenario would get us to the answer much faster :-)

Comment: So I'm getting almost the exact same behavior in plunker except instead of the typeahead being misaligned until an event, it just doesn't appear at all until an event. Try typing a single character, waiting a second, and then pressing something like the shift key. The typeahead only appears then. https://embed.plnkr.co/iy2Zhd5rEhBK2aVbBqsB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! NgZone ended up doing the trick, but I had to put it *inside* the callback, rather than wrapping it.

```
search(term: string) {
  if (term === '') {
    return Observable.of([]);
  }

  let result = Observable.create(observer => {
    this.autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({ input: term }, (results, status) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          observer.next(results.map(result => result.description));
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          console.log('Error - ', results, ' & Status - ', status);
          observer.next({});
          observer.complete();
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```